# Duda con beetween de mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
select
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_1,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_2,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_3,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '4' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_4,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '5' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_5,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '6' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_6,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '7' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_7,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '8' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_8,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '9' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_9,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '10' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_10,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '11' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_11,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '12' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_12,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '13' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_13,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '14' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_14,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '15' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_15,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '16' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_16,
sum(case when ticket_help_topic = '17' then 1 else 0 end) as helptopic_17
from gel_helpdesk where ticket_date BETWEEN '2019-05-01' and '2019-05-31';
```

y funciona bien.

Pero pasa lo siguiente:

Si las fechas que le paso son las que están ahora

```
BETWEEN '2019-05-01' and '2019-05-31';
```

En helptopic_6 acumulé 9 registros. (PERO ESTÁ MAL)

En la base de datos existen realmente 11 registros y no 9

Los 11 registros son estos: (todos con fecha de mayo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si el rango de fechas que busco lo modifico así: (ampliando el rango hasta el primer día de junio)

```
BETWEEN '2019-05-01' and '2019-06-01';
```

Ahora sí, en helptopic_6 acumulo los 11 registros.

¿Por qué? No entiendo, si los 11 registros todos están en mayo, por qué al extender la fecha a junio primero si lee 11 registros y si lo pongo hasta el 31 de mayo, solo me lee 9?

¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Opción 1**

- Recuerda que los campos de tipo `DATE` tienen un formato `YYYY-MM-dd` con un rango de:

> '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'

Repliqué tu ejercicio y aparte de lo que te comentaron, deberías tener tu consulta de este modo:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM demo
WHERE fecha BETWEEN "2019-05-01 00:00:00" AND "2019-05-31 23:59:59";
```

Dando un resultado de:

```
COUNT(*)
11
```

Recordando que los rangos de un campo de tipo `DATETIME` si abarcan la parte de `TIME` va de:

> '1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999'

Por lo tanto un modo de solucionarlo, es indicar en la fecha antigua la hora de inicio del día  que es `00:00:00` y en la fecha reciente colocar la hora final del día de este modo: `23:59:59`

**Opción 2**

Si aún así deseas en tu query solo consultar por: `YYYY-MM-DD`, entonces pasa por la función `DATE` la columna fecha así:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM demo
WHERE DATE(fecha) BETWEEN "2019-05-01" AND "2019-05-31";
```

Dando esto:

```
COUNT(*)
11
```

> Toma la parte `DATE` que se representa en este formato `YYYY-MM-DD` descartando el resto con lo cual tendrás tu resultado esperado.

**Ejemplos**

- `SELECT DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());`
- `SELECT DATE(NOW());`
- `SELECT DATE("2019-05-29 12:56:00")`

Para los 3 casos anteriores se ignora la parte `TIME` y opera para devolver la fecha de dichas funciones.

Referencias:

- [MySQL DateTime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)
- [Ejemplo funcional](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fddd60c0aee2c0cf5c7c9d3fb44a0d6c)
- [Función `DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Answer (score 2):

Es porque estás queriendo comparar como `DATE` sobre campos `DATETIME`, entonces lo que haces al comparar con

```
BETWEEN '2019-05-01' and '2019-05-31';
```

es buscar registros cuyos valores de `DATETIME`, y no `DATE`, correspondan al rango

```
'2019-05-01 00:00:00' y '2019-05-31 00:00:00'
```

Es decir, iniciando el día 31 de mayo como fecha final del rango. Si quieres buscar sobre la última hora que tienes registrada, puedes *hardcodear* el asunto con el `datetime`

```
2019-05-31 15:49:10
```

De otra manera, el agarrar el día siguiente `'2019-06-01'` (que es lo que estabas haciendo) es buena opción.